# Can not delete zip file from ftp server.Only zip files

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm using `FtpWebRequest`, and I can delete files & folders, upload, create, etc. but I cannot delete .zip files.

I have a recursive function that deletes all files and folders. When it hits a .zip file, the request throws an unknown exception with "System error" error message.

I have wasted half of the day with this issue. Does anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: could you please show us your code?

Comment: "System error". Does the debugger not tell you anything more? If debugging is not an option, take a look in the windows event viewer ("eventvwr.exe" from the run menu) and find the exception in the system log. There should be more info available.

Comment: What OS is the FTP server running on?

Comment: Have you checked the FTP server logs? Where do the ZIP files come from? Are they probably in the process of being moved or extracted? A lot more information is required, we can't see the issue from here.

Comment: the files are not in use, i`ve just uploaded them, and no, i haven`t cheched the server logs. Guess i`ll have to make a ticket for this, thanks

Comment: @FlorinV , did you check the event viewer on the machine where your client is blowing up? There's certain to be more information about what went wrong.

Comment: @Sudhakar nope, no extra details, just System error

Comment: @spender Nope, i`m not quite aquinted with Event viewer, how can i find exactly the errors that i`m interested in?

Comment: Oops. I meant the application log. Open eventvwr, choose "windows logs"->"application" in the treemenu on the left, and look for events with red icon at the time your app crashed. One of them should correspond to the failure.

Comment: @spender nope, no error related ...

Comment: @AndrewCooper The server is running CentOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path length was the main issue here.
Using **FtpWebRequest**, you dont use command like CWD or PWD, the class resolves the commands for you. After i`ve shortened my paths, i can delete anything i want.
The strange thing is that i could create those long named folders, and upload files in them without any kind of issue. The problem was revealed only when i tried to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the FTP server is treating the .zip file like a directory and allowing you to traverse into it, but does not support deleting files from the .zip.

Comment: i`ve thought of that but when i request WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails and it returns only a single line of text, not like when i run the same request on a foder and it lists all of the folder`s contents.